# JSON serialization in Jersey - How to ignore XmlJavaTypeAdapter for serializing a map?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

In my Jersey-based REST webservice I need to provide xml and json output. The class *Result* has a map, annotated with XmlJavaTypeAdapter to correctly serialize it to xml.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Result {

    private Map<String,Integer> results = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public Result(){}

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ResultMapAdapter.class)
    public Map<String,SearchResult> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

The XML output looks like:

```
<results>
  <result><name>Key1</name><value>Value1</value>
  <result><name>Key2</name><value>Value2</value>
</results>
```

And the json output looks like

```
  "result":[{
    "name": "Key1",
    "value": Value1
  },{
    "name": "Key2",
    "value": Value2
  }]
```

But I want that it looks like:

```
  "result":{
    "Key1": Value1,
    "Key2": Value2
  }
```

If I remove the XMlRootElement and the XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation, the json output looks like I wanted, but then the xml serialization failed. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is the use an custom ObjectMapperProvider. The Following provider doesn't create an combined mapper for json and xml. So the json serialization doesn't use the xml annoatation.

Of course the disadvantage of this sol

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public ObjectMapperProvider() {
        defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {

        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }


    private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {

        ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        result.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        return result;
    }
}
```